# Centering CSS transform:scale on grouped objects

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a circle and a rectangle grouped together in a SVG. I managed to increase their size when one of the objects is hovered, but the overall group is shifted. I tried to use `transform-origin` with different values (`50% 50%`, `center center`) without success.
How could the size of both objects increase around their respective origins instead?

```css
.zoom {
  transition: all .2s;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
   <g class="zoom">
      <circle cx="100" cy="75" r="50" fill="red"/>
      <rect x="200" y="50" width="70" height="30" fill="blue"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dypQRrW Sounds like what you are actually after.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D. `transform-box` put me on the way. I am trying to get the output of your second post, but both objects should scale when one or the other is hovered. But because objects are grouped together, `transform` refers to the center of the group I imagine

Comment: Try this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QWKJMwR

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect !